# jQuery .on and multiple scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm building a class in js where I use `jQuery.on()` to do some stuff. I know that I can use `bind` to make the scope of the class is referred to `this`, but this way it replaces the scope of the current object inside the `.on()` function. I'm using the old trick of `var self = this`, and it works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do that.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```js
var MyClass = function(settings){
    this.mySetting    = settings.mySetting;
    this.otherSetting = settings.otherSetting;

    this._initFunction();

};

MyClass.prototype = {
    mySetting    : '',
    otherSetting : '',

    _initFunction: function(){

        // keep a referente to the class scope
        var self = this;

        $('.selector').on( 'click', '.trigger', function(){

            if( self.mySetting == 'something' && self.otherSetting = 'some other thing'){

                // here, this is referred to '.trigger'
                $( this ).slideUp();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But, if I do this, the code doesn't work because the scope issue:

```js
var MyClass = function(settings){
    this.mySetting    = settings.mySetting;
    this.otherSetting = settings.otherSetting;

    this._initFunction();

};

MyClass.prototype = {
    mySetting    : '',
    otherSetting : '',

    _initFunction: function(){

        $('.selector').on( 'click', '.trigger', function(){

            if( this.mySetting == 'something' && this.otherSetting = 'some other thing'){

                // here, this is referred to 'MyClass', so it won't work
                $( this ).slideUp();

            }
        }.bind( this ) );
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to make this more elegant, avoiding the use of var `self = this`?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by removing the `var self = this;`?  This is a very common concept.

Comment: Is there a difference between the first set of code and the second?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, sorry! Just edited the code, now it's different! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `bind` to make `this` point to the MyClass instance and use the `event` object to get to DOM Elements that triggered the event.

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    mySetting    : '',
    otherSetting : '',

    _initFunction: function(){

        $('.selector').on( 'click', '.trigger', function (event){

            if( this.mySetting == 'something' && this.otherSetting = 'some other thing'){
                $( event.target ).slideUp();

            }
        }.bind( this ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `bind`, you can use [jQuery's `proxy` functionality](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to do essentially the same thing, but without worrying about old browsers' lack of support for `bind`.

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    mySetting    : '',
    otherSetting : '',

    _initFunction: function(){

        $('.selector').on( 'click', '.trigger', $.proxy(function (event){

            if( this.mySetting == 'something' && this.otherSetting = 'some other thing'){
                $( event.target ).slideUp();

            }
        }, this ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! That's a good tip, didn't knew until today what `$.proxy` is for, and the browser support is a valid point. I'll take it into consideration on my projects!